How to get urn for post sharing
I want any users with linkedIn profile to have ability to share posts from my app to their LinkedIn pages. The problem is that I need URN of user as required field, but I can't receive it
I get auth code with https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&state=123456&scope=openid%20profile%20w_member_social%20email, in scope I put all posible options from OAuth 2.0 scopes, after it I run
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&code=${authCode}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri} to get access_token, next step is https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo with header Authorization: Bearer access_token' and in response I get: { "sub": "", "email_verified": true, "name": "", "locale": { "country": "US", "language": "en" }, "given_name": "", "family_name": "", "email": "", "picture": "" }

, and no URN.
How to solve this problem?
